# Referring to PHP variable in HTML section of a PHP file

Tags: php, html, variables

I am trying to set up my own contact form (first time with PHP). My form works and an email is sent to me, but I'm having trouble getting the email to show the info the user inputs into the form.

**The HTML**

```
<label for="name">Your Name</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">

<label for="email">Your Email</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email">


<label for="message">Your Message</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**The PHP**

```
$to = 'email@email.com';
$subject = "Subject";

$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

$htmlContent = '
<html><body>

    <h2>Title</h2>
    <hr>
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif;">
        <b>Name: </b> ($name) <br>
        <b>Email: </b> ($email) <br>
        <b>Message: </b> ($message) <br>
    </p>
</body></html>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: email@email.com' . "\r\n";

$success = mail($to,$subject,$htmlContent,$headers);

if ($success){
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=success.html\">";
}
else{
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.html\">";
```

I'm simply not sure of the correct way to write the variable inside of the $htmlContent area.

Comment: Im no expert in php, but arent you supposed to use something like         
 `<b>Name: </b> <?php echo $name?> <br> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email should show "$name" instead of the user input, because your string says exactly that. To get the value of the variable into the string you have to concatenate the string with the value like this:

```
$name = 'foo';
$htmlContent = 'Hello World ' . $name . '!';
```

htmlContent would then be 'Hello World foo!'

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your HTML Content like a template

   ```
   $htmlContent = '<html><body>

   <h2>Title</h2>
   <hr>
   <p style="font-family:sans-serif;">
       <b>Name: </b> ({name}) <br>
       <b>Email: </b> ({email}) <br>
       <b>Message: </b> ({message}) <br>
   </p>
   </body></html>';
   ```

you will see i have replace actual name with {name} (in b/w curly braces), same with email and message

2. Before echoing html str replace template var with actual value

   ```
    $htmlContent=str_replace('{name}',$name,$htmlContent);
    $htmlContent=str_replace('{email}',$email,$htmlContent);
    $htmlContent=str_replace('{message}',$message,$htmlContent);
   ```
3. Then echo it

   ```
   echo $htmlContent
   ```

All in one:

```
$htmlContent = '
<html><body>

    <h2>Title</h2>
    <hr>
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif;">
        <b>Name: </b> ({name}) <br>
        <b>Email: </b> ({email}) <br>
        <b>Message: </b> ({message}) <br>
    </p>
</body></html>';
$htmlContent=sprintf($htmlContent, $name, $email, $message);
$htmlContent=str_replace('{name}',$name,$htmlContent);
$htmlContent=str_replace('{email}',$email,$htmlContent);
$htmlContent=str_replace('{message}',$message,$htmlContent);
echo $htmlContent;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the indepth reply :) I did test that and it worked - though I went with another members' post which was simpler. I appreciate the reply though.

Comment: no problem mate. But string concatenation is very tedious as you will find out some time later

Answer (score 0):

Rather like that:

```
<b>Name: </b> <?php echo $name ?> <br>
```

Or you can use the shortened version:

```
   <b>Name: </b> <?= $name ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

variables are not replaced with their values inside of single-quoted strings. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for details

Answer (score 0):

You could use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) with `%s` like:

```
$htmlContent = '
<html><body>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <hr>
    <p style="font-family:sans-serif;">
        <b>Name: </b> (%s) <br>
        <b>Email: </b> (%s) <br>
        <b>Message: </b> (%s) <br>
    </p>
</body></html>';
$htmlContent = sprintf($htmlContent, $name, $email, $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
“<b>Name:</b>”. $name.”<br>
```

You have to refer php variables like this use inverted commas to split html and php separate